# Implementing a simple slider in code?

Tags: css, javascript

Here's where I'm at. Have inserted this into a page's html code:

```
<div id="stgSlideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="https://staging.retrorigs.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/AdjustedA2600-scaled.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="https://staging.retrorigs.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/cropped-Zen-Gardens-Gallery-1-scaled-1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     Test text here...
   </div>
</div>
```

Have added the CSS below via Customise>Additional CSS:

```
/* SLIDER */
#stgSlideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#stgSlideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

Lastly, I have updated my Header.php file to include some javascript to rotate the slides:

```
<?php
/**
 * The header.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until main.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twenty_One
 * @since Twenty Twenty-One 1.0
 */

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> <?php twentytwentyone_the_html_classes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#stgSlideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
            setInterval(function() { 
                $('#stgSlideshow > div:first')
                    .fadeOut(1000)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn(1000)
                    .end()
                    .appendTo('#stgSlideshow');
            },  3000);
        });
    </script>   
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php wp_body_open(); ?>
<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwentyone' ); ?></a>

    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/site-header' ); ?>

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
```

Sadly, not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't insert `<script>` tags into WordPress's template files. The proper way to add Javascript code is to use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

If I'm reading this right, it appears you're using jQuery code, so you'll need to ensure that `jquery` is in the `$deps` array in your `wp_enqueue_script()` call.

Also, [WordPress uses jQuery in `noConflict` mode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#comment-1473), which means you need to either a) do a bit of extra work to ensure that `$` is available, or b) replace `$` with `jQuery` in your code.

### Sample code

You can add this to your active theme's `functions.php` file.

**`functions.php`**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse384608_slider_script' );
function wpse384608_slider_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 
         'my-slider',
         get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/slider-script.js',
         array( 'jquery' ),
         '1.0.0',
         true
    );
}
```

The last parameter in the `wp_enqueue_script()` call, the `true`, tells WordPress to load the script  in the page's footer. If you need it loaded in the header, change this to `false`.

You'll need to move the JS code in your question to a file in your theme, at `{theme root}/js/slider-script.js`.

**`js/slider-script.js`**

```
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#stgSlideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
        setInterval(function() { 
            jQuery('#stgSlideshow > div:first')
                .fadeOut(1000)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .end()
                .appendTo('#stgSlideshow');
        },  3000);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply + whoa - this just got a whole lot more complicated! Reading through the enque script link, but it's a little baffling. What would example code look like?

Comment: I've added some sample code. You may need to tweak it for your particular use, but it should be a good starting point.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. You nailed it, thanks.